# How check visibility of alerts using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

One alerts popup is appearing after saving data. How to check popup visibility using Selenium with java

Comment: what you need to check for visibility or you have to move to popup question not clear yet? and please add source for better understanding

Comment: I need check whether that popup is appearing or not. If appears then i need to get text and click ok button. This is my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use ExpectedConditions like below to check whether the alert is present or not like below:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())==null)
    {
    System.out.println("No alert");
    else{
    System.out.println("Alert present");
        }
    }
```

To accept that alert you can use:

```
  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

To close that alert you can use:

```
  driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

To send some values to the alert box you can use:

```
  driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Text");
```

We can also use try-catch block like below:

```
   public boolean alertPresent() 
   { 
   try 
   { 
    driver.switchTo().alert(); 
    return true; 
    }   
   catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
   { 
    return false; 
    }    
    }
```

Comment: `else{}` can't handle the _TimeOutException_ inacse `if()` fails rather you need to fall back on `try-catch{}`

Comment: Yeah correct, In that case you can use try-catch block and I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
```

This will help you to switch to the alert popup window and you can check for the visiblility.

Comment: @J-Alex You have Approved the edit for this answer where the submitter added the phrase **check for the visiblility** (along with a spelling mistake) within the answer which makes the answer **unuseful** and will be prone to _downvotes_. Please introspect.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov You have _Approved_ the edit for this answer where the submitter added the phrase **check for the visiblility** (along with a spelling mistake) within the answer which makes the answer **unuseful** and will be prone to downvotes. Please introspect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Find the xpath or id of the popup let's take one example

```
                WebElement popUp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the popup"));

                if (popUp.isDisplayed()) 
                {
                    WebElement btnOk = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the button in alert"));
                    btnOk.click();
                    System.out.println("Pop up displayed and button clicked");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Pop up Not found");
                }
```

their is second way you can handle alerts and check if that presents

```
     try
     {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println(alert.getText()+" Alert is Displayed"); 
     }

        catch(NoAlertPresentException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Alert is NOT Displayed");
    }
```

Comment: Any reason for the _REFERENCE_ not being a part of your answer?